# EclipseLink PreUpdate on OneToOne Relationship not persisted

Tags: jpa, eclipselink, entitylisteners

I have a PreUpdate method which gets executed, but when flushing the entityManager the changes on the dependent entity are not persisted.

Following is my minimal (non) working example:

**Entities**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "HOUSE")
public class House {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private long id;

    @OneToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinColumn(name = "INFO_ID")
    private HouseInfo info;

    @PreUpdate
    protected void komplettiereEingabeWerte() {
        info.setCode("TEST");
    }

    //getters and setters
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "HOUSE_INFO")
public class HouseInfo {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "CODE")
    private String code;

    //getters and setters
}
```

**Testcase**

```
@Test
@Transactional(TransactionMode.ROLLBACK)
public void testPreUpdate() {
    House house = entityManager.find(House.class, 1L);
    house.setInfo(new HouseInfo());
    entityManager.flush();
    entityManager.clear();

    house = entityManager.find(House.class, 1L);
    assertEquals("TEST", house.getInfo().getCode());
}
```

The Test fails due to an AssertionError on the last line as Code is null.

I am using EclipseLink version 2.7.4 with an Oracle DB (the same behaviour was also observed with an in memory Derby DB) and the Test is running with UnitilsJUnit4 in a SpringApplicationContext.

How can I fix this problem? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [JPA Spec](https://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/persistence-2_1-fr-eval-spec/JavaPersistence.pdf?AuthParam=1565013951_3c7c0e4ae31976d25267ebd25f3d6754) states that:

> In general, the lifecycle method of a portable application should not invoke EntityManager or query operations, **access other entity instances**, or modify relationships within the
>   same persistence context. A lifecycle callback method **may modify the non-relationship
>   state** of the entity on which it is invoked

The simple answer is, then, that entity listeners cannot be used for the task. Implement the relevant logic in your service layer instead.